# How the /sbin directory in host Buildroot is generated?

Tags: compilation, executable, buildroot

I'm using buildroot 2020.02.1 to build an embedded system.

Does anyone knows how the host/sbin directory is used for in Buildroot output ?
I want to understand how buildroot generate this directory and how can you configure buildroot to change the configuration of this directory.

My problem is that all the output/host/sbin files have an application/x-sharedlib type but I want to change the type in order that they can be executable.

Does anyone knows how to do ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

`host/sbin` contains all tools that Buildroot builds for the host, which are needed for building other software components for the target. I suggest you to read https://bootlin.com/doc/training/buildroot/buildroot-slides.pdf to get an overall understanding.

What specific file in host/sbin is a shared library? You should only have executables in this directory.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, All of these file are in "bibliothèque partagée (application/x-sharedlib)" type and I don't know how to change this. ( 85 files from adpart to zic file)

Comment: please do you know how to compile buildroot without the --enable-default-pie options. I think i should modify CFLAGS but i don't know how and in which file.